# With Flask how to show my data from my CSV file (JSON) on a webpage?

Tags: python, html, csv, flask

I would like to show the content of my CSV file on a simple webpage like this :

Do you know with Flask what i have to do with this >

I am quite new on Flask,i read the tutorial basic for Flask but don't totally get it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using tablib for that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
import tablib
import os

app = Flask (__name__)

#fun var

dataset = tablib.Dataset()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'out.csv'))) as f:
    dataset.csv = f.read()


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return dataset.html


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Much cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution (edited out from the question):

Nevermind I found the solution myself :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask (__name__)

#fun var

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'out.csv')

open_read = open(filepath,'r')
page =''

while True:
    read_data = open_read.readline()
    page += '<p>%s</p>' % read_data
    if open_read.readline() == '':
        break

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return page


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```